# Filtro para exibir resultado em relatorio em Excel com banco MySQL e PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Não estou conseguindo criar um filtro por meio dessa `query` que filtra uma pesquisa no banco *MySQL* com *PHP*. Comecei a editar ele, mas o problema é que não consigo gerar esse método utilizando uma variável que está presente na tela. Por exemplo, fiz da seguinte forma:

```
$result = $obj->getAll('usuarios_id IN (SELECT usuarios_id FROM usuarios WHERE empresas_id = 12');
```

Nesse caso ele funciona, e exibe os resultados da `empresa_id = 12`. Estou tentando modificar para passar um parâmetro ao invés de valor fixo (12). Tentei assim:

```
$result = $obj->getAll('usuarios_id IN (SELECT usuarios_id FROM usuarios WHERE empresas_id = ".$empresa."');
```

Não me retorna nenhum resultado. Estou tendo dificuldades de passar esse parâmetro de `$empresa`. O método ficou assim:

```
public function excelRelatorio() { $arrayRow = array('Nome','Forma Pagamento','Status', 'KM','Valor', 'Valor Extra', 'Data'); $this->geraExcelRelatorio($arrayRow); }

private function geraExcel($arrayRow,$empresa)
{


    $this->load->helper('xls');

    $arr[] = $arrayRow;

    $obj = new Viagem();
    $result = $obj->getAll('usuarios_id IN (SELECT usuarios_id FROM usuarios WHERE empresas_id = ".$empresa."');


    if (isset($result) && count($result) > 0) {

        foreach ($result['rows'] as $v) {

            $arr[] = array(

                utf8_decode($v->getUsuario()->getNome()), $v->getFormaPagamento()->getNome(), $v->getStatus()->getNome(), $v->getDistancia(), $v->getValor(), $v->getValorExtra(), dataHoraBr($v->getDataCriado()), $v->getEntregador()->getNome()

            );

        }

    }

    array_to_xls($arr, 'financeiro'.date("m-d-y").'.xls');
}
```

Comment: `"usuarios_id IN (SELECT usuarios_id FROM usuarios WHERE empresas_id = '{$empresa}'"` tente assim.

Comment: consegui obrigado